# Error en mi arreglo CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

estructure un arreglo para que almacenara las direcciones url para que fuera mas dinamica a la hora de traer las url

> Como antes lo tenia

```html
array(
        'name'  => 'inicio',
        'url'   => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/emprende/admin/index.php/inicio',
        'icon'  => 'gi gi-home'
    )
```

> Mi arreglo

```html
"array(". 
        "'name' => " . "'".$pant["pantallas"][0]->nombre_pantalla."',".
        "'url' => " . "'http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . "".$pant["pantallas"][0]->url."'".",".
        "'icon' => " . "'".$pant["pantallas"][0]->icono."'". 
        "),"
```

y asi es como se muestra

**array('name' => 'Invitados','url' => 'http://localhost/emprende/admin/index.php/invitado','icon' => 'fa fa-user')**

segun yo es practicamente lo mismo pero lo malo es que no me estra trayendo la url y solo me manda el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque en tu segundo array tienes dobles comillas (sencilla y doble)

Comment: hola, lo que pasa es que por ejemplo nombre tiene comillas entonces tambien se las estoy concatenando

Comment: el problema es que `"array(".   "'name' => " .` simplemente es un string, por eso no puedes acceder a la info

Comment: pero no estoy accediendo a la info, todo es simplemente texto plano excepto cuando ya accedo a mi arreglo para traer los datos